# Flatbutton is invisible. It is not showing asset image on Flatbutton

Tags: image, flutter, assets, invisible, flatbutton

it's a code of a main file

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("RTSPS"),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: FlatButton(
      child: Image.asset('assets/1st.png'),
      onPressed:()=>HomePage(),

      ),
    ),
  ),
  );
 }
}
```

and here is `pubspec.yaml` file code in which I only made changes in assets

```
assets:

  - assets/1st.png
```

Comment: This could be due to a syntax issue in pubspec.yaml file (incorrect spacing), or issue with hot reloading. Try rerunning app.

Comment: In a terminal, run `flutter pub get` from project root.Please paste the full code in`pubspec.yaml`